# Getting 503 error while fetching data from Rest API

Tags: java, api, okhttp

I have one POST API which fetches data with limit 25 000. There are nearly 1 600 000 records. But while fetching data in one application, it is getting stuck at 1250 000 records. What can be done?

It's working fine on postman but what I noticed is it is taking records on loop every time 25 000. Maybe that is taking time and server is not able to handle request?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to do pagination in this case.
you can read records in a sorted manner and the next time when you fetch the next 25k records pass the last sorted key you read.

This is a standard way to fetch data because you can not ask for 160k records at a time from the database. that will put a lot of load on database.

also while fetching 25k you can do that in batching to avoid memory footprint.
maybe in the batches of 1k.